# Performance difference between SELECT * and SELECT TOP(1)

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

In our legacy code we have VB statement that translates to:

```
SELECT Id FROM Table
WHERE IdentifierId = 1
```

This returns just short of 900 000 entries and the count is increasing each day. The whole idea is to get the last `Id` + 1 (achieved in VB by taking the highest `Id` and adding 1 to it), so I'm wondering if, and by what margin, the following would be better:

```
Select TOP (1) Id FROM Table
WHERE IdentifierId = 1
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Any insigth on the performance difference is appreciated.

PS: `Id` and `IdentifierId` are forming a composite key for `Table`.

Comment: Why would you *not* expect a performance difference between those 2 queries?

Comment: @ThomA I'm expecting there to be a difference, the question is if it is enough to justify fiddling with legacy code.

Comment: You should [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). The whole idea of getting the largest Id and adding 1 to it probably indicates something dubious though.

Comment: *"the question is if it is enough to justify fiddling with legacy code."* We don't know; we can't run your query, nor do we know what the performance difference was when you did your tests.

Comment: The index `(identifierid, id)` -- in that order -- should make the second query virtually instantaneous.

Comment: A better solution that avoids scanning a table or index to get the highest number is to change the application to write the Next Number to a NextNumbers table after each INSERT of the main table. This all depends on the work load and the ratio of reads to writes of course but in a write light, read heavy system, it will be the fastest option.  So although your proposed code will reduce the data coming back to the application, it still isn't scalable as the whole table must be scanned to find the highest number.

Comment: FWIW - I think @MartinSmith has the right of it. It sounds like there's something like an implicit autoincrement column at play here which can be better solved in several ways.

Comment: @BenThul, @MartinSmith - thanks both for your comments. The system is old and not well-designed - there is no need for a composite key and just having `Id` as the primary key would've removed the need for my question. Anyway, I'll try to measure performance when I get the chance.

Comment: To be clear, having an autoincrement column and having said column be a primary key are orthogonal concerns. For example, you could get the value for the Id column from a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, or in a similar situation, I've measured the two approaches. The `SELECT Id FROM Table` on average took about 1.1** seconds, whereas `Select TOP (1) Id FROM Table` took 0.00* seconds. The `TOP (1)` statement was, as @The Impaler suggested, almost instantaneous.